# Maclaurin Series for $f(x,y) = xe^y$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was solving Taylor series problems for my calculus class and was stuck with this concept.

Suppose a function,

$$f(x,y)=xe^y$$

And we know that for $f(y)=e^y$, the Maclaurin series exists as

$$e^y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n}{n!}$$

Then, can I simply multiply $x$ to the series above such that:
$$f(x,y)=x \cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n}{n!}$$

Because $x$ is not varied by any $n$ terms, is it possible to just multiply it?

I'm greatly confused and would appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Comment: Even though this is a function of two variables, in regards to just the summation, x can be considered a constant. By properties of constants and sums we have $C\sum a_n=\sum C a_n$

Comment: Then it is correct to denote it as,
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x\cdot\frac{y^n}{n!}$$

Comment: yep it's nicer as $\frac{x y^n}{n!}$